# Como evitar que o app seja "minimizado" pelo AppSwitch(RecentApps) Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Necessito bloquear o dispositivo somente para uma aplicação.

Utilizo no meu projeto uma linha que determina que o meu app vire um `launcher`. Sendo assim, a tela inicial do dispositivo é o meu aplicativo e o `HomeButton` acaba por direcionar sempre para o aplicativo. Linha abaixo.

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionMain }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryHome, Intent.CategoryDefault })]
```

Consegui bloquear os botões para evitar que o usuário acesse as configurações do dispositivo por meio da alteração dos arquivos `*.kl` dentro da pasta /system/usr/keylayout. Porém a única maneira de realizar esta alteração é com o dispositivo *rooteado*. Estou buscando maneiras para não precisar *rootear* o dispositivo.

O `BackButton`, consigo "bloquear" no dispositivo dentro da minha aplicação, utilizando o `public override void OnBackPressed()`.

Os botões de volume eu consigo "bloquear" no dispositivo utilizando o código que segue abaixo.

```
    public override bool OnKeyDown(Android.Views.Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
    {
        switch (keyCode)
        {
            case Android.Views.Keycode.VolumeUp:
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Volume Up pressed", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                e.Dispose();
                return true;
            case Android.Views.Keycode.VolumeDown:
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Volume Down pressed", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                e.Dispose();
                OnUserLeaveHint();
                return true;
        }
        return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
    }
```

Porém, o único botão que não estou conseguindo "bloquear" é o `AppSwitch`, que é o mais fácil para acessar as configurações.

Tentei com o código que segue abaixo, porém sem sucesso.

```
protected override void OnPause()
{
    base.OnPause();

    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)GetSystemService(Activity.ActivityService);
    activityManager.MoveTaskToFront(TaskId, 0);
}
```

A barra de tarefas eu faço o bloqueio também. Porém somente dentro da aplicação.

Li também sobre `AccessibilityService`, onde podemos alterar criando um Hook nos botões pressionados. Porém não consegui muita informação e os testes que fiz foram sem sucesso.

Alguma ideia de como bloquear?

---

Continuo com as tentativas. Este infelizmente está sendo tentativa e erro.
Acessei o [Android Management API](http://developers.google.com/android/management) e configurei uma empresa, criei uma política e consegui importá-la para o dispositivo. Porém, não existe uma maneira de bloquear as configurações do dispositivo(até porque é uma das maneiras de restaurá-lo as configurações padrões), que é um dos itens necessários para minha aplicação.

Não queria apelar para os arquivos .kl que somente funcionam com o dispositivo rooteado. Alguém tem alguma idéia?

Comment: Tentei por este caminho que segue - Android Management API: https://developers.google.com/android/management/. Porém sem sucesso ainda

Answer (score 1):

Depois de muita pesquisa e conversa com outros colegas, descobrimos que no método `OnPause()` é possível bloquear o botão `AppSwitch(RecentApps)` utilizando o código que segue abaixo.

```
    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();

        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager.FromContext(this));
        activityManager.MoveTaskToFront(TaskId, 0);
    }
```

Podem acontecer alguns "bugs" se pressionado muitas vezes seguido, como por exemplo, tela piscando preta, porém somente quando é pressionado muitas vezes seguidas.